# Maven release plugin : creating tag and branch simultaneously

Tags: maven, maven-3

Team,

We are using maven release plugin and wanted to create branch and tag (together) while running maven release:prepare goal.

We tried following configuration but it seems only tag is getting created. It is not creating branch.

```
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <branchBase><<Branch URL>></branchBase>
                <tagBase>
                    <<Tag URL>>     
                </tagBase>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <svn>javasvn</svn>
                </providerImplementations>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the Maven Release Plugin to do this. Or you do a release with `mvn release:prepare` and a tag gets created. Or you want to create a branch and you use the `mvn release:branch` command (See http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html for more info on that)